# Move element forward in list (SML)

Tags: list, sml

Is it possible to just move an element in a list forward in SML, let's say two steps, so that the 3 in `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` ends up like `[1,2,4,5,3,6]`?

Comment: Take a look at `List.take()` and `List.drop()`

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie Yeah, I thought about that, but is there any way to make a certain element jump two steps forward? Like when you hit the 3 in the list, it jumps forward no matter where in the list it might be (the position is unknown).

Comment: I don't think so, the variables in SML are immutable, unless declared as references, but I can not tell what might be the properties of a reference variable to an array (if there are any).

Comment: You have to "move" not only the `3` but `4` and `5` as well so that you have a continues block of data in your memory. So yeah, best performance will be `O(n)`.

Comment: I see, I guess I'm trying to solve the "wrong" problems. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you will need to define a helpful function that returns the exact position of the element that you want to change. In this you will have something like this, assuming you have only one 3 in the list. If you want to move all the 3s forward, just make the curr (position) a list:

```
exception DoesntExit 
fun look3 (li, curr) = if (hd(li) == 3) then curr else look3 (tl(li), curr + 1)
  | look3 (nil, curr) = raise DoesntExit
```

Now you have the exact position curr of the 3 you want to move forward, all you need to do is to use combination of List.take() and List.drop() which is trivial to have your desired output.

This method is not limited with which element you want to change, neither the list length, nor the list type.